# Problema al obtener y leer array que recibo por restclient

Tags: php, array, rest, objeto, formato

Tengo ya codificados en PHP muchos script donde recibia por api (rest) los datos en un formato, pero por una modificacion en la misma, los recibo de otra manera, y quisiera saber si hay forma de formatear estos datos de otra forma para no tener que modificar todo el codigo en la manera de extraer las variables. Le explico con ejemplos:

Antes recibia la informacion de esta forma, luego de un print_r, por ejemplo en $result:

```
Array
(
    [body] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 11111111
            [nickname] => NICK
            [registration_date] => 2015-06-23T08:30:52.000-04:00
            [first_name] => nombre
            [last_name] => apellido
            [gender] => 
            [country_id] => AR
            [email] => eeeeee@aaaaa.com
            [identification] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [number] => 1112221111
                    [type] => Otro
                )
)

    [httpCode] => 200
)
```

y obtengo por ejemplo el nickname de esta forma:

```
$nombre=$result['body']->nickname;
```

lo que me da como resultado 11111111

Ahora, con la version nueva, obtengo de la misma forma, en $result, este otro formato:

```
Array
(
    [0] => {"id":11111111,"nickname":"NICK","registration_date":"2015-06-23T08:30:52.000-04:00","first_name":"nombre","last_name":"apellido","gender":"","country_id":"AR","email":"eeeeee@aaaaa.com","identification":{"number":"1112221111","type":"Otro"}}
)
```

Y no sé como obtener el mismo dato del ejemplo anterior

Lo que necesitaría, es saber si se puede modificar el formato para tener que modificar lo menos posible todos mis script, lo ideal sería que de alguna forma quede con el mismo formato exacto. De no ser posible, como al menos puedo presentar de una mejor forma el script ya que con print_r (se muestra el resultado con los tag pre y /pre utilizados) en el 2do ejemplo sale todo en 1 sola línea. Y tambien de ser imposible igualar el formato, como obtengo el dato nickname de ejemplo

Comment: Solo cambió `body` por `0`, entonces accedes con `$nombre=$result[0]->nickname;`

Comment: Si, lo intenté pero no trae nada de esa forma

Comment: Tienes que usar `json_decode` para que te lo convierta a json y entonces podrás leerlo como indica @Triby.

Comment: Me funcionó como dijo A. Cedano, esta muy bien lo que dijo @Triby, solo faltaba aplicar el json_decode al indice 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La estructura que muestras es un array con un elemento dentro, el cual es un json.

Entonces, si lo quieres leer de una forma sencilla puedes:

1. Aplicar `json_decode` al índice `0` del array
2. Leer el resultado de forma normal, usando la notación `$json->propiedad`.

Por ejemplo:

```
#$response sería tu dato actual
$response=array (
'{
   "id":11111111,
   "nickname":"NICK",
   "registration_date":"2015-06-23T08:30:52.000-04:00",
   "first_name":"nombre",
   "last_name":"apellido",
   "gender":"",
   "country_id":"AR",
   "email":"eeeeee@aaaaa.com",
   "identification":{
      "number":"1112221111",
      "type":"Otro"
   }
}');
    
    
$json=json_decode($response[0]);
echo $json->nickname.PHP_EOL;
echo $json->identification->number;
```

**Salida:**

```
NICK
1112221111
```

Comment: Genial mil gracias por la ayuda, funciona perfecto